# jquery invoke 500 InternalServerError

Tags: jquery, web-services

But only on our production server.  Works great in every other environment.  The web service runs just fine on production, I don't understand what's (apparently) corrupting the exception I throw from it in production.

First, the jquery.  When a checkbox is checked, we call a web service to try to do what we call "Token Assignment":

```
        if (chk.is(":checked")) {
            chk.invoke('AssignToken',
            params,
            function () {
                //Go up the tree to the category, then down into the header to find the count.
                var spnTokenCount = $this.closest('.category').find('.tokenCount');
                var tokenCount = 1;
                if (!isNaN(spnTokenCount.text())) {
                    tokenCount = parseInt(spnTokenCount.text());
                    tokenCount--;
                    spnTokenCount.text(tokenCount.toString());
                }
                if (tokenCount == 0) {
                    $this.closest('.category').find('.spnAvailable').hide();
                    $this.closest('.category').find('.spnPurchase').show();

                    //Let's find the unchecked elements and not allow them to be selected.
                    $this.closest('table').find('.tokenAssignment').find('input:checkbox').each(function (index, element) {
                        if (!element.checked) {
                            element.disabled = true;
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                chk.attr('checked', false);
                var response = '';
                eval('response = ' + xhr.responseText);
                if (response.ExceptionType == 'xxx.TokenAssignmentException') {
                    alert('Token assignment failed, you may be out of tokens.');
                } else {
                    alert('Token assignment error.');
                    //alert('Token unassignment failed\n\n' + response.ExceptionType + '\n' + response.Message + ':\n' + response.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        );
```

In my base page, I have the following WebMethod:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void AssignToken(int accountId, int courseId, int studentId, string studentType, Guid userId)
    {
        try
        {
            CourseToken ct = CourseTokenFactory.AssignToken(accountId, courseId, studentId, studentType, userId);
            if (ct == null)
            {
                Logger.Error("Token assignment attempt failed for " +
                    accountId.ToString() +
                    ", course " + courseId.ToString() + ", student " + studentId.ToString() +
                    " of type " + studentType);
                throw new TokenAssignmentException("Token assignment attempt failed.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("Failed trying to assign token for account " +
                accountId.ToString() + ", course " + courseId.ToString() +
                ", student " + studentId.ToString() + " of type " + studentType, ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

We see both log messages getting written, so the web service is acting appropriately (in this case.  Getting back a null CourseToken from the factory means that we didn't find one available to be assigned).

As you can see in the jquery error handling method, I check the response's ExceptionType for the type of exception I threw in that case, and give a little more friendly error.

However, on production, xhr.responseText is turned into "There was an error processing the request", with ExceptionType of empty string.  In all other environments, xhr.responseText is what we expect, with ExceptionType being the fully-qualified class name ('xxx' for anonymousization), and we get the more-friendly error message.

I'm not really sure how to debug this further.  I've verified through the log messages we're creating and throwing the exception type we expect, and with firebug that it's not in the xhr object when it gets back to the client.  (But only in one environment).

Or is this a more fundamental problem with the approach?  Should, perhaps, the WebMethod be returning boolean, or the CourseToken which got assigned, or something (false/null to indicate non-assignment) instead of a specific exception type?

Comment: That error is not because of the jQuery. It is a.) because you didn't submit the proper data to a server-side process that expects data a certain way. or 2.) because there is an issue in the server-side script or process. Since this is a web service my bet would be 'a'. Check the browser console during the process and make sure that you see the proper information transmitted to te web service.

Comment: Thanks Jay, but we see the WebMethod run _exactly_ as it should, and Firebug shows the parameters going in just right.  See answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is the answer, but I hate that I can't write paragraphs in the response editor.

I can't take credit for this, my product manager (who likes to be geeky) found this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/290881/exceptions-thrown-from-webmethods-are-swallowed-by-resthandler-when-httpcontext-iscustomerrorenabled-true

The difference is, we have customErrors set to RemoteOnly on the production webserver, so the exception I throw from the web service is swallowed in that environment.

I feel pretty confident about this being the answer; we RDP'd to the webserver, started a browser there and hit the production app with the exact same demo account we'd been testing with from browsers outside the server.

Got the 'friendly' message, which means the xhr object maintained the ExceptionType from the one which the web method threw because we don't have custom errors locally.

So I guess the lesson here is not to use exception to handle this condition.  I'll have to rewrite the service and the two ajax good/error methods.  Make the web method send back a bool or the object/null or something to indicate assignment worked/not, and handle true exceptions in the error handler.